# Add ripple effect to a listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add ripple effect to MvxListView but its not coming. Here is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/orientedlayout"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <cgs.bw.droid.CustomCalendar
                android:id="@+id/customcalender"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/txtActivity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/strActivity"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                        android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                        android:textColorLink="#7e1664"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:id="@+id/viewActivity"
                        android:background="#7e1664"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtNews"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/strNews"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                        android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                        android:textColorLink="#7e1664"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:id="@+id/viewNews"
                        android:background="#7e1664"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#e3e3e3" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.6"
                android:id="@+id/ActivityLinLayout"
                android:minHeight="80dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/NoActivityFeed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    local:MvxBind="Visible (ActivityfeedData.Count==0)"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_login" />
                <FrameLayout
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <Mvx.MvxListView
                        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ActivityfeedData ; ItemClick ShowDetails,Mode=TwoWay"
                        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/homeactivity_itemtemplate"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NewsLinLayout"
                android:layout_weight="1.6"
                android:minHeight="80dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="right">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/gear_icon_states"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        local:MvxBind="Click EditFeedList"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/NoNews"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        local:MvxBind="Visible (FeedItemsTotal.Count==0)"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_login" />
                    <FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:visibility="visible">
                        <Mvx.MvxListView
                            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FeedItemsTotal; ItemClick ShowNewsDetail,Mode=TwoWay"
                            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/homenewsfeedtemplate"
                            android:minWidth="25px"
                            android:minHeight="25px"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/txtAllEventsAndMeetings"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/strAll"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            local:MvxBind="Click GoFetchAllMeetingAndEvents"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                            android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                            android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                            android:textColorLink="#7e1664" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:id="@+id/viewAllEventsAndMeetings"
                            android:background="#7e1664" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/txtEvents"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/strEvents"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            local:MvxBind="Click GoFetchAllEvents"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                            android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                            android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                            android:textColorLink="#7e1664" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:id="@+id/viewEvents"
                            android:background="#7e1664" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/txtMeetings"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/strMeetings"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            local:MvxBind="Click GoFetchAllMeetings"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                            android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                            android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
                            android:textColorLink="#7e1664" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:id="@+id/viewMeetings"
                            android:background="#7e1664" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="right">
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/strToday"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:tag="RobotoCondensedBold"
                    android:textColor="#4a90e2"
                    android:textColorLink="#7e1664" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:minHeight="80dp">
            <TextView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:text="@string/NoMeetingsforthisMonth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tv_no_evnt"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="gone" />
            <Mvx.MvxListView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/mvl"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:animationCache="false"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource _MeetingList; ItemClick ShowMeetingDetail,Mode=TwoWay"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/border_5dp"
                tools:visibility="gone"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" and android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" but the effect is not showing up-. There os nothing else applied on the listview.

Here is the list_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/lg_pressed_state">
  <item android:drawable="@color/purple_bw"/>
</ripple>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I endend up achieving this wrapping the item layout inside a LinearLayout and added the ripple to it.

Please try and let me know:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rltContent"
        android:background="@color/youBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Your content here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ripple example:

```xml
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</ripple>
```

Comment: No.. It doesnt work.! Is it the complexity of my layout causing this.?

Comment: Are you testing this in a pos API 21? Please try my solution with a simpler layout. Just to ensure it works. Then keep adding your layout slowly.

Comment: Okay.. Will try and let you know.. Thanks for the solution.. :) :)

Comment: Any progress with it?

Comment: Its working with a simple layout but not with my layout. Don't know whats causing the problem. Thanks a lot for your help. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I always had success when setting `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` to the list item and adding a onClick listener (without the listener, there was no ripple when clicking on the item).

Maybe it also works by setting this background to the whole list or in a style; otherwise, you'll have to make a separate layout file for the list item.